# Using post instead of put in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5 for creating restful api, is it right way to use post method instead of put method for updating a record, as I see no difference in using the both, as the complete logic for updating a value is written inside my controller, it will be helpful if someone suggest which is right method to go a head.

Comment: You should follow global standards for API. Read this to answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/q/630453/5350773

Answer (score 1):

You should use `PUT/PATCH`. That's a non-arguable. It is a standard in implementing RESTful APIs just like PSR standards.

There's a reason why there are different HTTP verbs.

An excerpt from an article:

> The HTTP verbs comprise a major portion of our “uniform interface”
>   constraint and provide us the action counterpart to the noun-based
>   resource.

See article [here](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `POST`, but I wouldn't recommend it. If you want to update data, there should be used `PUT`.

What if later you want to change something in create method with `POST`, which you doesn't really want in update?

I recommend to read a bit, f.ex. I found last time really helpful article:

[REST flowcharts](https://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/2.0/guide/rest_flowcharts/)